# Default Xcode 4.5 font

Tags: xcode, fonts, default

What is the default font and font size in Xcode 4.5? I ask because Im trying to configure Eclipse to use the same syntax colouring and editor font as Xcode.

**Edit 03.08.2013**

For future reference: I used [Eclipse Colour Themes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&q=xcode) to automatically set the syntax colouring properties in Eclipse, rather than manually configuring individual colours, which is a tediously annoying  (if not painful) process to do within Eclipse.

Comment: Open your excode and check.

Comment: I'm on a windows machine. I wouldn't be asking otherwise.

Comment: Even I am in windows, Used TeamViewer to check :p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Font : Menlo Regular - 11.0

syntax colouring: See image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer/screenshot. Although I used http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&q=xcode for the syntax colouring, much easier than manually configuring individual colours.

Answer (score 4):

The default one is `Menlo Regular - 11.0`

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to point out that the default one now in Xcode 8.2.1 is `SF Mono Regular - 11.0`. Maybe someone finds it helpful.